# How to set Outer width in jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I have faced miss alignment issue in my table and i found the reason outer width value as wrong . so if it possible to set outer width value as 0.

one more information i am must be use outer width property for my alignment . if i am setting outer width instead of width . i have faced on another issue . so i have used outer width my td.

Thanks all

Comment: We could better help you if you presented: (a) the relevant rendered HTML code, (b) the jQuery version your are using, (c) the jQuery code your are attempting to debug, (d) relevant CSS, and (e) what you have done so far, even if it didn't work so far. This way we can better help you.

Comment: does the element has a margin.... if not set [box-sizing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) to `border-box`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont quite understand what you mean by setting outerWidth to 0.

Outer width is just width + paddings( or + margins if using outerWidth( true ) )

Just set your elements padding and margin to 0.

Comment: Thanks for your replay , if i am setting padding as 0 ,the outer width return value as 1

Comment: Did you set margin to 0, and borders to 0, and made sure that they actually are 0, and no other CSS rule overrides those values ?

Also, if outerWidth returns 1, in your script somewhere, then just treat it as 0...close enough.

Comment: thanks ... working fine, i reset my padding and margin working fine thanks for your help